# Why is the definite article "the" used in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

> Explain how **the** addition and removal of energy can cause a phase change.

Is it still correct or does it still mean the same if the definite article "the" is removed and zero article is used instead in this particular example?

Comment: Could you provide more context or something? I'm pretty sure I know what you're talking about, but if we assume this is a question intended for students, there must be a text preceding it in which these terms have been explained or discussed, right?

Comment: @userr2684291 When you want a substance to change states, you either increase (add) or decrease(remove) its internal energy.

Comment: You haven't said anything new. Could you tell me more about the context in which this question was asked? Is my assumption right – you talk in detail about changing states, and then at the end you ask the highlighted question?